# Visual Studio Code debugger disapearing after first call

Tags: javascript, typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I currently have an azure function deployed to azure, where my code is locally in my repo.

[image: Code Repo]

For some reason, if i launch the debugger (F5), everything works as expected and i get the following output:

[image: Output]

When I call my azure function (From browser or postman via a GET call), I get my response in my browser but my debugger just randomly disappears and it looks like the output window is bugged too.

Please also assist me in adding more necessary information to this post since I don't really know what information could be useful on this issue.

[image: Debugger window]

Also my output of the terminal gets stuck after a couple of seconds when my code is debugging

[image: Terminal Stuck]

The solution to this is pressing (ctrl+C) to cancel my terminal command and restart my function.

Is there any specific reason this might happen?

I have a .vscode folder with all the required attachments and files, Code:

extensions.json

```
  "recommendations": [
    "ms-azuretools.vscode-azurefunctions"
  ]
}
```

launch.json

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to Node Functions",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9229,
            "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
        }
    ]
}
```

settings.json

```
    "azureFunctions.deploySubpath": ".",
    "azureFunctions.postDeployTask": "npm install (functions)",
    "azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "TypeScript",
    "azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~3",
    "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
    "azureFunctions.preDeployTask": "npm prune (functions)"
}
```

tasks.json

```
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "func",
            "command": "host start",
            "problemMatcher": "$func-node-watch",
            "isBackground": true,
            "dependsOn": "npm build (functions)"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "npm build (functions)",
            "command": "npm run build",
            "dependsOn": "npm install (functions)",
            "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "npm install (functions)",
            "command": "npm install"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "npm prune (functions)",
            "command": "npm prune --production",
            "dependsOn": "npm build (functions)",
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```